# What is the best choice to use as a synonym for [invision-power-board] and [ipb]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

There are two tags ([invision-power-board](/questions/tagged/invision-power-board) and [ipb](/questions/tagged/ipb)) that refer to the same piece of software. I believe they should have a synonym created but I don't have a score of 5 in either tag.

Neither tag refers to the [proper name](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1948964#1948964) of the software, which is [IP.Board](http://www.invisionpower.com/apps/board/).

I'd like to suggest a synonym, but I'm unsure which tag (if either) to use. What is the appropriate course of action for these two tags?

Comment: It *did* use to call itself Invision Power Board before abbreviating the company name part.

Comment: This has reminded me of the old school IPB, especially 1.3 with billions of security flaws.

Comment: @BoltClock That's what I recall too, I just can't find any proof of this.

Comment: @Stijn: There are a number of sites running older versions with the default theme, which displays the full name in the header.

Comment: Yes, Invision Power Board was the former name.  Created by the guy that did Ikonboard.  Source: Both are ripoffs of the Ultimate Bulletin Board, which was my responsibility for five years, I know my former competitors.  :p  Given the current product name, [tag:ip.board] should be created and the other two should become synonyms of it.

Comment: @Charles: If it's any comfort to you, I am aware of (read: I remember) UBB. I can imagine why you would call them ripoffs - for every board I came across running UBB, there were probably hundreds of IPBs and vBulletins.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, yup, they moved faster and took design and feature risks that my bosses wouldn't.  They deserved to win market share at the time.  Ah well, can't change the past... unless you happen to have a time machine handy.  My past self could use some exceptionally *violent* re-education.